# Disable window resize when changing focus

Tags: vim

I have a single vim-tab with multible windows. When i change the focus to another (vim-)window, vim seems to impose a minimal window width. For example, if i have 2 open windows split vertically, a change of focus to the right one results in shifting the seperators a bit to the left (1 character, i guess the terminal-width is odd) , and vice versa. This is annoying especially when there are more windows, since moving around changes the layout of the tab.

i tried setting `wfw`, but now when i open another window (again split vertically) the new one will have width 1, and `Ctrl-W =` doesn't work any more.

Is there an option to disable resizing on focus change, while still beeing able to `Ctrl-W =`?

**Edit:** I'm running vim 7.4, beeing the official debian jessie vim-gnome package. The behaviour is reproducable even without `.vimrc`. I'm using `urxvt`, and `xterm`  shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your setup? I don't remember ever seeing the behavior you describe when moving the cursor to another vertical window.

Comment: Sounds like it could be your `winwidth` to me.  If you `:set winwidth=1` does that resize your splits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly went wrong, but the problem was caused by using the session file i created with [vim-obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession).
Deleting this file and starting a new session fixed the above.

Comment: You probably have set some kind of local option like `'windowminwidth'`. If you get yourself into the situation again it would probably be best to figure out which settings are causing the behavior. I would start by looking at `:setlocal` and `:set`. Those commands will display the current settings